# Union types support in Relay

Tags: relayjs

When you have defined field as an union of two types (in example machines contains Ships and Droid) then in Relay you can do something like that:

```
fragment on Faction@ relay(plural: true) {
  name,
  machines {
    ... on Ship {
      name
    }
    ... on Droid {
      name,
      primaryFunction
    }
  }
}
```

so under machines prop your objects are correctly evaluated, but if you want to do that using fragments from external components:

```
fragment on Faction@ relay(plural: true) {
  name,
  machines {
    ${StarWarsShip.getFragment('ship')}
    ${StarWarsDroid.getFragment('droid')}
  }
}
```

then you end up with fragment definitions under machines. It looks like you are trapped and can't check which object is which type in machines array so you can't decide which component should be used.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/268

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There exists a `__typename` field with which you should be able to introspect the type of each record:

## Query

```
fragment on Faction @relay(plural: true) {
  name,
  machines {
    __typename  # <-- add this
    ${StarWarsShip.getFragment('ship')}
    ${StarWarsDroid.getFragment('droid')}
  }
}
```

## App code

```js
this.props.faction.machines.map(machine =>
  machine.__typename === 'Droid'
    ? <Droid droid={machine} />
    : <Ship ship={machine} />
);
```

Comment: …as of https://github.com/facebook/relay/commit/ea2f5faae753526e1a76e70b05d262c4b2662570

Comment: I'm running into this problem when I try to do like you've written:

Uncaught Error: GraphQL validation/transform error ``Type `undefined` doesn't have a field `__typename`.

Comment: What version of Relay, and what version of the Babel Relay plugin are you running?